# If $T:V\longrightarrow V$ is diagonalizable, then $T$ has a characteristic polynomial of the form $f(x)=(x-c_{1})^{n_{1}}\dotsc(x-c_{k})^{n_{k}}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, diagonalization

If $c_{1},\dotsc, c_{k}$ are the distinct eigenvalues of $T$ and $W_{i}$ is the eigenspace of $c_{i}$, then $T$ has characteristic polynomial of the form $f(x)=(x-c_{1})^{\dim W_{1}}\dotsc (x-c_{k})^{\dim W_{k}}$.

How do I prove this?

Comment: What did you try? When can we say that a map is diagonalisable? Do you know any condition?

Comment: Well, $T$ is diagonalizable if there exists a basis $B$ for $V$ such that each element of $B$ is an eigenvector of $T$. I want to prove that for each $c_{i}$, there is an element of $B$ that belongs to $W_{i}$. Such elements form a basis for $W_{i}$. I want to show that but I don't know how.

Comment: Ok, what's the dimension of the $\ker(T-c_i I)$ ?

Comment: I still have no idea. That's what I want to find. But I know that $\ker (T-c_{i}I)=\dim V - \text{rank} (T-c_{i}I)$.

Comment: @ShuichiSaihara Can you add these two comments of yours to your question post? They will make the question better since your doubt is more specific than the original question. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

First there's a typo:  should be eigenvalues  $c_i $.

You have that $PAP^{-1}=\Delta $, where $\Delta  $ is diagonal with  $\rm {dim}(W_i) \,c_i $'s on the diagonal for each $i $.

But the characteristic polynomials of similar matrices are the same, because  $\rm {det}(A-\lambda I)=\rm {det}(P (A-\lambda I)P^{-1})=\rm {det}(\Delta-\lambda I) $, by linearity and the fact that the determinant is a homomorphism.

Now, nothing is left but to compute the characteristic polynomial of $\Delta $.

Comment: I think the question is not just what appears in the title, but also the part in the body about the algebraic multiplicity being the same as the geometric multiplicity for diagonalizable matrices.

Comment: You're right.   I will include something about that.  @angryavian

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer. If $B$ is an eigenbasis of $T$ for $V$, then $[T]_{B}$ is diagonal. Hence for each eigenvalue $c_{i}$, $[T-c_{i}I]_{B}$ is diagonal, and the nullity of a diagonal matrix is equal to the number of zeroes on the diagonal.